# Chrome Extension, jQuery is not defined, sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm loading a code programmatically when the user click on the browserAction icon of my extension, and sometimes it works, sometimes I have the `jQuery is not defined` error.

Here's my code :

```
var injectElementLoaded = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (!injectElementLoaded) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "/resources/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "/resources/js/my_script.js"});
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "/resources/css/my_script.css"});

        norbertSidebarLoaded = true;
    }
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "jQuery('body').trigger('execute-stuff')"}); // This is throwing issues
})
```

I correctly defined jQuery at the top, but I'm guessing it's not enough.
I thought about adding a `setTimetout` to my last call code, but I don't know how much to wait.

Is there a way to ensure my scripts are loaded before calling the last line ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If between the first click of the extension icon and a second click there is navigation on the tab, or if you switch tabs, you'll be trying to execute the last line of code in a context where the other scripts did not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback function which is called after executing the script. That is, you should rewrite the code above as like the following:

```
var injectElementLoaded = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  var trigger = function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {code: "jQuery('body').trigger('execute-stuff')"}
    );
  };
  if (!injectElementLoaded) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {file: "/resources/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"},
      function() {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tab.id,
            {file: "/resources/js/my_script.js"},
            function() {
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS(
                  tab.id,
                  {file: "/resources/css/my_script.css"},
                  function() {
                      norbertSidebarLoaded = true;
                      trigger();
                  });
            });
      });
  } else {
    trigger();
  }
});
```

If I try to apply ES2015...

```
var injectElementLoaded = false;

const executeScript = (tabId, file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: file}, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

const insertCSS = (tabId, file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {file: file}, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

const trigger = (tabId) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tabId,
    {code: "jQuery('body').trigger('execute-stuff')"}
  );
};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  if (!injectElementLoaded) {
    executeScript(tab.id, "/resources/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js")
      .then(() => {
        return executeScript(tab.id, "/resources/js/my_script.js");
      }).then(() => {
        return insertCSS(tab.id, "/resources/css/my_script.css");
      }).then(() => {
        norbertSidebarLoaded = true;
        trigger(tab.id);
      });
  } else {
    trigger(tab.id);
  }
});
```

Anyway, you should use the callback function.